# Java as external component using Swing: main thread never exits

Tags: java, swing, tomcat

I am trying to use a Java component inside another program. The program is a Web Application running on Tomcat, and my component uses Swing to open a web browser. The user is prompted to navigate to a specific page, and using controls on the JFrame, the page is saved locally in HTML format. This locally saved file will be used later for further elaboration.
The problem is that, when executed from Eclipse, my code works without flaws. When I use the component inside the Application running on Tomcat, however, it's not running correctly. The window appears, navigation is working, and the data gets retrieved without problems. The thing is that the main app (the one running on Tomcat) has to resume its execution after the component (Java) has done its work. Evidently, something goes wrong, as the web app simply hangs, and never continues.

In my component, I use two classes: a Browser and a Helper. The Browser is based upon the DJ NativeSwing libraries and contains the logic to initialize and display a simple web browser. The Helper class provides me with a "front-end" method which allows me to execute the browser in its own thread. I am using SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait instead of invokeLater, as it's not quite clear to me how to use wait() and notify(). I tried and failed.

Summing up the code, it would look something like this:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface;

public class Helper {
    public String Browse() {
    Browser vb = new Browser();
    try {
        Browser.log("This is Helper, now initiating.");
        NativeInterface.open();
        Thread th = new Thread(vb);
        Browser.log("Helper is invoking thread...");
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(th);
        NativeInterface.runEventPump();
        Browser.log("Thread exited! Back to Helper!");
        System.out.println(vb.getData());
        Browser.log("Returning data to caller: \n" + vb.getData());
        return vb.getData();
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Browser.log("MainFail: " + ex.getMessage());
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

And the Browser class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.NativeSwing;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser;

public class Browser extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton btn;
    private JWebBrowser webBrowser;
    private JPanel panel;
    private String data = "";

    public static void log(String s) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter ostr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("F:/java_out.log", true));
            Date dt = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
            String str = formatter.format(dt) + "\t -> " + s + "\n";
            ostr.write(str);
            ostr.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Logger: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Browser() {
        Browser.log("Initializing...");
        NativeSwing.initialize();
        NativeInterface.open();

        panel = new JPanel();
        btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText("Save Page");
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        btn.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        VisureBrowser.log("Button is ready!");

        JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        webBrowserPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Navigate and save"));
        webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
        webBrowser.setButtonBarVisible(true);
        webBrowser.setMenuBarVisible(false);
        webBrowser.setLocationBarVisible(true);
        VisureBrowser.log("Panel is ready!");

        this.setTitle("Simple Browser");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        VisureBrowser.log("Frame is ready!");

        this.add(btn, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        btn.setVisible(true);
        webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        webBrowser.setVisible(true);
        this.add(webBrowserPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(true);

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Browser.log("Constructor: " + e.getMessage());
            Browser.log(e.getStackTrace().toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Browser.log("Look and Feel ready as well! Off to work...");
    }


    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }


    public void close() {
        WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);
    }


    public void run() {
        Browser.log("Navigating to the index page...");
        webBrowser.navigate("http://www.google.com/");
        Browser.log("Navigation successful!");
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Browser.log("An action has been performed!");
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if (src.equals(btn)) {
            try {
                Browser.log("Getting data...");
                this.data = webBrowser.getHTMLContent();
                Browser.log("Closing...");
                this.close();
            } catch( Exception ex) {
                Browser.log("ClickFail: " + ex.getMessage());
                Browser.log(ex.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

The output I am getting is, from Eclipse:

```
12:28:54     -> Initializing...
12:28:55     -> Button is ready!
12:28:55     -> Panel is ready!
12:28:55     -> Frame is ready!
12:28:56     -> Look and Feel ready as well! Off to work...
12:28:56     -> This is Helper, now initiating.
12:28:56     -> Helper is invoking thread...
12:28:56     -> Navigating to the index page...
12:28:56     -> Navigation successful!
12:29:04     -> An action has been performed!
12:29:04     -> Getting data...
12:29:04     -> Closing...
12:29:06     -> Thread exited! Back to Helper!
12:29:06     -> Returning data to caller:
.....here comes all the data.....
```

and the data I am getting when executing inside Tomcat is the following:

```
12:28:54     -> Initializing...
12:28:55     -> Button is ready!
12:28:55     -> Panel is ready!
12:28:55     -> Frame is ready!
12:28:56     -> Look and Feel ready as well! Off to work...
12:28:56     -> This is Helper, now initiating.
12:28:56     -> Helper is invoking thread...
12:28:56     -> Navigating to the index page...
12:28:56     -> Navigation successful!
12:29:04     -> An action has been performed!
12:29:04     -> Getting data...
12:29:04     -> Closing...
```

Yes, I used the same lines, but the output is this, it only goes until the closing line.
The thing that I did not expect is the delay between the closing of the window and the resume of the main activity: around 2-3 seconds per run. I immagine it has something to do with the secondary (GUI) thread not exiting properly, but I am at a loss as to how to proceed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish with this? Why launch a browser from a web server? Why not just serve a URL for the user's browser to visit?

Comment: The web app I am working on acquires data relevant to a specific subject on an internal database. This data may as well originate from an external source, as in another public service. What I am trying to do is acquire this data, parsing it from the HTML file. It is already done, the only detail is that I cannot access the data from my application. Therefore I present the user with a native browser which allows him to navigate to the page he wants, and I have all the HTML-data available.
I have tried with jQuery, Ajax and whatnot: cross-domain requests have me blocked... :/

Comment: Also, the code that invokes all this and then prints the "Thread exiting" message is the code that's failing to operate correctly, but I can't find it here. What thread are you talking about?

Comment: You still didn't answer the question: why doesn't the user launch the browser themselves to visit your application? How does this web app get started of the user hasn't launched a browser?

Comment: The web app is started from a separate module. It runs on Tomcat, inside a browser. So, when I launch the application, it is already inside a browser. The java part, my component, acts as a "library" to this application, and I simply invoke the Browse() method. That is, inside my web app I have the line:
String data = Helper.Browse();
and that's it. The window appears, I browse and then click the button. The messages are produced in a text file (F:/java_out.log), as you can see. 
I really don't know how to become more clear.

Comment: The Tomcat webapp doesn't run inside a browser. It runs on a server, potentially without any screen attached, and potentially miles away from the user's machine. The user will stare at its browser while the webapp, on the server, waits for input in the JFrame that is displayed on the server screen (if any). On your development machine, the server and the client machine are the same, but in production, that won't be true anymore. Hence the question.

Comment: Hmmm, I can see where the confusion comes from. I am pretty new to the whole idea as well, so I beg your pardon.

Here is the thing: I am working on a relational IDE which produces its own files (be it Java, ASP.NET or whatever) and uses Tomcat to provide its services. All I know is that. 

What I do is import the component, written by me in Eclipse, and try to accomplish the aforementioned result. The code and output I've included are my own, I have not included anything else. And I was hoping it would be sufficient, in all sincerity...

Comment: Oy, oy oy! When I was commenting before, I was on my iPhone, so I couldn't see all the code at once and I didn't grasp the enormity of the situation. You are using some kind of SWT library to access Swing? Why, why, why, when Swing is already right there in the standard API? If you *must* do this -- and you still haven't convinced me that you must, not by a long shot -- then why, oh why, would you use this weird third-party Swing/SWT bridge thing when you can simply use Swing directly? I am actually starting to wonder if this is a troll.

Comment: I am not a troll, perhaps I am not so well-versed in the use of Swing, but as I already said, I am pretty new to all this stuff. And, again, I beg your pardon. As I said before, I have a full-fledged application which can be accessed from any registered user, and I need to be able to import data relevant to the user, data which resides on another server and is only available in HTML. I cannot have the credentials of the user inside my application, so I want to provide him with an interactive way to see, hence acquire, his data.

Comment: Nobody said I MUST do this, it's just that I didn't have any other guidance, and wanted to try this solution out. I tried pure Swing, but the web browser it produced did not have the functionality I was expecting (it was horrible...), therefore I found the "weird Swing/SWT bridge" which allows me to invoke a native web browser (if I've correctly grasped the meaning). Anyway, I was successful in resolving the issue I initially posted, it was indeed a threading problem. Thank you anyway for taking the time to question me, it's always a good thing to have productive feedback! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

Tomcat is a web application server and should not be popping-up any Swing components. If the server were running elsewhere, every user would end up launching Swing windows on the server and the user would never see them. What you are experiencing (Tomcat launching a Swing window and being able to actually see it) is just a coincidence because your server is running on `localhost`.

What you want to do is have your users start from a web browser, then navigate to the correct site to consume your content. That is, the web browser should already be available: you shouldn't have to launch one on your users' behalf.

Comment: You are correct. I have no idea how this will behave when executed under real conditions, however I must make sure it does what I want in local first. It is not the best practice, but that's the only way I've got, for now. My problem, in its very base, is that although the browser is already available, I haven't come up with an alternative way of acquiring the info of the user.

Comment: What "info" do you need? How are you getting it with this awkward setup?

Comment: I am developing a database which collects the subject's fiscal data. Evidently, it is a rather sensitive matter, and I want to do it in the best way possible. I am currently considering other choices as well, but I don't think there is any simple way to acquire it... :/
My last investigation has led me to believe cross-domain communication using a proxy PHP script might be the way to go. What are your thoughts on this? :)

Comment: I think you have no idea what you are doing. I don't understand why the application server needs to launch a web browser... if the user needs to access your service via a web browser, the user will launch the browser and go to the URL for your service. If you need information from the user, then ask for it via a web form.

Comment: The idea has been actually abandoned, it was more of a personal "try and error" thing. I really have no idea what I'm doing, and I know how this sounds, but I want to believe I'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Just write a plain-old web application with HTML as the interface. Then use the a browser to access it. There's no need for Swing to be in the mix.

Comment: Agreed! :) I am currently working with Servlets and JSP (since I already have Tomcat available) and trying out some other solutions, but I already have a simple plain HTML page guiding the user through the process, as you suggest.